# How to overlay elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation menu with tabs and I use negative margin to group the elements and I want the active element to stay over the inactive elements. I used `position: absolute` but it had no effect. How can I do this?

```css
.nav-item {
  margin: -40px;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #F2BF5E !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

.nav-link.active {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div style="margin-top: 10%" class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <ul style="display: flex; justify-content: center;" class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-warning" role="tablist">
      <li (click)="teste('entrar')" class="nav-item" style="width: 200px;">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#link1" role="tablist">
                 Entrar
                 </a>
      </li>
      <li (click)="teste('cadastrar')" class="nav-item" style="width: 200px;">
        <a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#link2" role="tablist">
                 Cadastrar
                 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, this is what I have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdYQd.png)

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I didn't pay attention

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @JeremyLucas FYI, if you type `[es.so]` in a comment, it expands to [es.so]. Ditto with `[pt.so]` => [pt.so] and [more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331106/194720).

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4.3.1

Comment: Looks like they're overlapping fine. In the code provided, the "Cadastrar" pill doesn't have a background. You'd need to have an alpha channel of < 1 defined for the background color to show through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want an image to be on top of the other, and vice versa, based off of whether it is 'active' or not.

In this case, I would imagine using the z-index is what you would want. It is a CSS property that provides depth/stacking based off of an integer value.

```
.nav-link.active {
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}
```

You might have to modify your code a bit to get it to how you want exactly; I'm just trying to provide a concept. You can just toggle the z-index value based off of whether it is 'active'

Comment: I did try use z-index, but also it had no effect

Comment: Did you include a position value that isn't static? e.g. position absolute

Comment: I did include "position: relative" and now it works. Thank you for your help, and sorry for my english :D